# 'XXX のような事をしたい' という文脈で XXX のタグを付けるのは適切でしょうか？

Tags: 討議, タグ

例えば「Rubyで書かれたプログラムをPythonに書き換えたい」といった文脈の質問で、両方のタグが付けられているケースがあります。

説明のため、元となるタグ側のプログラムやコマンド等が質問文に含まれていることもありますが、質問や回答のやり取りは実現したいこと(上記の例ならPython)が焦点になるはずで、別のユーザーが(上記の例ならRubyについて)検索する際にノイズとなる可能性があります。

このようなタグの付け方は適切でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

私は、別に両方のタグがつけてあっても良いかなと思っています。変換元と変換先、両方の意味が分かっていないと回答しにくいだろうからです。

タグは、エキスパートと、エキスパートが回答できる質問とを結びつけるための手段です。このため変換元を理解できることが回答に重要であれば、そのタグをつける理由のひとつになります。Ruby らしさのあるコードが変換元になっているのであれば Ruby のエキスパートに質問をアピールする理由になりますし、[ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) タグをつけておく意味があるでしょう。

逆に言語機能やアルゴリズムなどを表すための手段として Ruby を選択しただけであれば、[ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) タグをつける強い理由は無いでしょう。ただ、手段が Ruby でなくても良いとはっきり分かっている場面は少ない印象です。たとえば「この機能を何というか分からないのだけど Ruby ではこう書けるものを、Python だとどう書けますか？」のような形です。このような質問で Ruby のエキスパートの興味を引くために [ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) タグをつけるのは、そこまで迷惑じゃないのではと考えています。

質問者さんが「あくまで一例として Ruby で書いてるだけだが……」という意識があるなら [ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) タグは不要です。そうでも無い限り、別に [ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) タグがついてても迷惑とまでは言えないかなというのが私の考えです。このような意味で、変換元と変換先、両方のタグがあっても良いかなと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

少なくともタイトルや質問文中で明示されるべき内容ですが、タグ付けに値する情報ではないと思います。

「XXX で書かれたプログラムを YYY に書き換えたい」という質問があったとすると、この質問での焦点は、「YYY では (XXX の) **この機能をどう実現するか**？」という点です。そのため、機能の具体的な説明が行なえるならば、 XXX という言語名は、実現したいことをより短く、明確に伝えるための**補足情報としての意味合いが強い**と感じます。

> 別のユーザーが(上記の例ならRubyについて)検索する際にノイズとなる可能性があります。

確かに検索する際のノイズになる可能性はありますが、両方のタグが付いていることで、

- XXX から YYY への書き換えを問題としている人
- YYY から XXX への書き換えを問題としている人

の両方に 1 つの質問で対応することが出来、どちらのタグにとっても有用な投稿となる可能性があるため、「両方のタグが付いているから、ただちにどちらかのタグに搾らなければならない」ということは無いと思います。